# Endless Scroll for Greasemoney

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, infinite-scroll, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'm trying to adapt this userscript for other site i'm browsing , but without any succes .

http://pastebin.com/eU8HDHX0

I only need the `var EndlessScroll` part from line 580, but i seem to break it when removing all the other functions .

The site i plan to use it on seems to have the same pagination tehnique as original script :

index >  /site/images.php & the pagination is made like this : site/images.php&page=2 , /site/images.php&page=3 , etc .

I've also tried a obsolete version of http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-in-greasemonkey/ , but again failed to make it work ;

Sadly my coding skills resume to basic html/css editing , so i come here to look for some proffesional help <3 . I only need a 'cleaner' version of the script to use it in greasemonkey . Thank you !